# Coin tossing probability

Tags: probability

What’s the expected number of times you need to toss a fair coin until you see both
a heads and a tails at least once?

Why is the answer 3 and not 2? Because I would need to flip the coin at least twice to get one each.

Comment: The *minimum* number of times needed is $2$, but the minimum is different from the *expected* number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you get on your first flip, your situation is: stop when you get the opposite.

On any given flip, the "average" number of heads (or tails) you will see is 0.5 (as the coin is fair), so you need two more flips to get 1 of the opposite you got on the first flip (on average)

So it's your initial flip (1) + 2 more flips = 3 flips

**If you want the math:**

After the first flip, let's say expected number of flips till you see the opposite is E .

So on your next flip with p = 0.5 you get the opposite and with p = 0.5 you are back to where you started.

So:

E = 0.5*1 + 0.5(1 + E)

0.5E = 1, E = 2

So the total expected flips = 1 + E = 3

Answer (score 3):

On the first flip, you'll definitely get one of them. Then, as you wrote, the expected number of flips to get the other one is $2$, for a total of $3$. For a generalisation, see the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).